# Reading symbols in GDB takes a long time

Tags: mongodb, macos, emacs, gdb

I download the mongodb source code and compile it with `scons --nostrip mongod` option,  then I use `emacs` `gud-gdb` start it.

it is in `Reading symbols from /Users/zhifan/github/mongo/mongod...` for 20 minutes, and still in progress.

is it possible to make it faster?

an interesting thing is I found the memory size of gdb process stopped at 2489MB for some time,  is there any hard limit on this?  since it is reading,  suppose the memory size should increase if no limit?

```
PID   COMMAND      %CPU  TIME     #TH    #WQ  #PORT MEM    PURG   CMPRS  PGRP PPID STATE    BOOSTS        %CPU_ME %CPU_OTHRS UID       FAULTS   COW    MSGSENT    MSGRECV  SYSBSD     SYSMACH  CSW        PAGEIN IDLEW   POWER
5706  gdb          74.5  20:15.49 1/1    0    11    2489M  0B     0B     5706 1698 running  *0[1]         0.00000 0.00000    110079271 899329   225    179712485+ 18608+   546535786+ 1903     179995118+ 3385   0       74.5
```

when I use `dtruss -p {pid of gdb}`,  I can see the following output all the time.

```
sigaction(0x8, 0x7FFF5FBFF018, 0x7FFF5FBFF040)       = 0 0
sigreturn(0x7FFF5FBFF508, 0x1E, 0x7FFF5FBFF040)      = 0 Err#-2
write(0xF, "\0", 0x1)        = -1 Err#35
sigaction(0x8, 0x7FFF5FBFF018, 0x7FFF5FBFF040)       = 0 0
sigreturn(0x7FFF5FBFF508, 0x1E, 0x7FFF5FBFF040)      = 0 Err#-2
write(0xF, "\0", 0x1)        = -1 Err#35
```

GDB version:

```
LM-SHC-16502651:mongo zhifan$ gdb -v
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0.1
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
```

Update:

1. I used gdb 7.11.1, 7.12, 8.0.1 on **Mac OS**, all of them have this
   issue.

I tried gdb 7.11.1 on **Ubuntu 16.06** and it works.

This probably a ** gdb on macos ** issue.

2. On Mac OS: gdb a hello world program works as well.

Update 2:

finally, I go to Ubuntu 16, and everything goes well then.

Comment: There have been bugs in `gud-gdb`, where it does equivalent of `info sources`, forcing GDB to read in *everything*. I'd try to first use command-line GDB to see whether it also suffers from such slow loading.

Comment: Thanks @EmployedRussian,  but I get the same result even I use command-line gdb.

Comment: Just a guess, but it looks like it is setting a signal handler for artithmetic execption, then getting a response that says a system call doesn't exist. Are you setting it to compile for Mac not Linux?

Comment: hi @jenesaisquoi,  I didn't do such tricky thing.   I install the gdb with `brew install gdb`.  and I also tried to compile the gdb with './configure ; make; make install', I got the same result.

Comment: no, I meant when you compiled mongo, I would guess this is not a gdb issue

Comment: Thanks @jenesaisquoi for this direction.  I compile mongodb with `scons --nostrip mognod mongo`.  but I use the same way to compile it on ubuntu, I didn't see this issue when using gdb